# Jquery and ajax only working from within an iframe

Tags: jquery, magento, iframe

I´ve been researching this all day and can't seem to find the right answer to my predicament.

I'm working on this Magento based store that uses a template that works with both prototype (this is what Magento works with by default) and jQuery with the noConflict trick. Everything seems to work just fine in Firefox, but when I open the exact same page in Chrome and IE7 most jQuery code and even ajax is non-functional.

Now it gets interesting because if I load my page via an iframe and open it in Chrome everything works just fine!

Is there any reason why this is happening? Do you have any pointers on what is the problem?

This is the website I'm working on: http://www.lavioletera.com.mx/compras/

Thanks in advance

Comment: damn it slow. Works just fin in Chrome for me. Tried F5?

Comment: no - definately works fine for me in Chrome.(except for 1min 10 seconds load time hehe - enable gzipping).

Comment: I think it's just not working in a very specific version of Chrome (one before the latest), but what really bothers me is it not working in IE7 because most of my market still uses it :S

Comment: And about the loadtime, I think it's a comnination of not enabling gzipping and a very slow server.

Comment: and magento being a terrible resource hog. yes yes:)

Answer (score 0):

well. when I open it in ie7 - there are 3 errors:

1. Line 67 char 3(Expected identifier, string or number)
2. Line 4025 char 9 (Object doesn't support this property method)
3. Line 4082 char 9 (Object doesn't support this property method)

It doesn't tell you in what file this error happen.
Chances are that if you look up these lines you'll be able to figure out what's wrong.

No errors in Firefox and Google Chrome.
I also don't see errors in IE8 and IE9.

P.S.
To see where problem happens exactly in IE7, go to:

**tools->Internet options->advanced tab** and make sure that "disable script debugging" is unchecked.

You might also install MS script debugger: [download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22185)

This way when you refresh the page - you'll see exact script location where error happens.

**UPDATE 1:**
in you jquery main file, max: 205 variable has comma at the end - you should remove that, as it's not supported by IE:

```
 function initKwicks(){

    jQuery.fn.kwicks = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            isVertical: true,
            sticky: false,
            defaultKwick: 0,
            event: 'mouseover',
            spacing: 3,
            duration: 500,
            max: 205, //no comma should be here!!
```

**UPDATE 2.**
Someone also mention that: "it is important that you include the jquery.js file before the prototype.js file"- I do not see how that affects it though.